# Python: Filter a series of lists by sign of elements

Tags: python

I've a nested `list` that looks like this

```
list = [[1,2,3,4],[-1,-2,-3,-4],[1,2,-3,-4]]
```

I'm trying to find a way to keep only the lists where all values have the same sign. So in this case, the first two lists nested within `list` would be kept and the third would be removed.

Does anyone have suggestions for how this could be achieved?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The other answers already provided one-liners solutions.  I personally find those to be hard to read, and therefore hard to debug.  Instead, I prefer solutions that spell out each step on a separate line.

With that said, let's try a simple `for` loop.

```
originalData = [[1,2,3,4], [-1,-2,-3,-4], [1,2,-3,-4]]
returnData = []

for sublist in originalData:
    if all([x >= 0 for x in sublist]) or all([x <= 0 for x in sublist]):
        returnData.append(sublist)

print(returnData)
```

Comment: Thanks Tim! I appreciate the other solutions, but do have trouble following comprehensions. I think this should do the trick for what I need.

Comment: @user3418064 Sure thing!  I did still use comprehensions in the `if` condition, but they're much simpler since they're only trying to solve one component of the problem, instead of the whole thing.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a set comprehension to basically build up sign bits (`1` if positive `0` if negative). If the length of that set is `1` then all the signs are the same, if it is `2` then they're mixed signs.

```
>>> data = [[1,2,3,4],[-1,-2,-3,-4],[1,2,-3,-4]]
>>> [sub for sub in data if len({i > 0 for i in sub}) == 1]
[[1, 2, 3, 4], [-1, -2, -3, -4]]
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use a nested list comprehension, comparing each element to the first of each sublist:

```
list1 = [[1,2,3,4],[-1,-2,-3,-4],[1,2,-3,-4]]
new_list = [b for b in list1 if all(i < 0 if b[0] < 0 else i >= 0 for i in b)]
```

Output:

```
[[1, 2, 3, 4], [-1, -2, -3, -4]]
```